# How can someone/something be described as both old (not new) and old (attained an advanced age), a friend and a friendship for example?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Some adjectives--for example: new, old, bad, good—may have two meanings, one of which taken separately, may or may not deny the other, for example:

Old:   of long duration (not new), and *attained an advanced age*

New:  not of long duration; having just (or relatively recently) come into being or been made or acquired or discovered, and other than the former one

Good:  of moral excellence, and with or in a close or intimate relationship

Bad: capable of harming, and characterized by wickedness or immorality

More generally, the question is this:

Can a noun be modified by the same two adjectives that, taken separately, have different meanings, the other meaning is capable of just been guessed? Would it help the interlocutor to guess the difference in meaning of the two by adding some adverb—really, actually, genuinely for example, like in"He is an old and really/ actually/ genuinely old friend of mine?

Specifically, the question is:

How can something both old (of long duration; not new) and old (attained an advanced age) such as a friend be described?

Comment: How about *an old old friend*? (:

Comment: @userr2684291 That's just what I was thinking of before asking. Are you going to expand it into the answer? I'd be delighted if you would.

Comment: "Old as in age" can be replaced with *aged* and "old as in a long time" can be replaced with *long-time*, if you really have to be specific.

Comment: aged is rather formal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two meanings of old: not new and advanced age.

Short answer: **Using the same word twice in English is emphatic**. Generally, if I say this is an "old, old friend", the repetition emphasizes the idea of long standing and not age.

Also, generally, one would not call a person **an old friend** directly and be referring to age. That would be considered very rude.

And if one is talking about that friend to another person, one might say: "You know that old friend I have?" In the context of a conversation, that **could be referring to age**. And if clarification is needed: "**You know that old friend of mine, old as in age**?" old as in age can be expressed many, many ways. (Oops, there's that emphasis.)

And if, in that same conversation with another person **out of earshot of the friend**, you wanted to use both meanings, you might say something like:

- You know that old friend of mine, age-wise and time-wise? or

- You know that old friend of mine, in both senses of the word?

That makes the two meanings clear.

A similar situation arises with the word **funny**. "He's a funny, funny man." means **very funny**. However, funny can mean both comical and odd (weird). Saying **funny twice**  means **very funny**.

So, for "He's a funny man.", if there is ambiguity, it can be lifted by saying: "He is a funny man, in both senses of the word. It can also be clarified: "He's a funny man, funny ha ha". or "He is a funny man, as in odd".

Comment: What about *an old old friend*? See, I omitted the comma because you can read *old friend* as one unit (and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20friend) even defines it as one vocabulary item). In that case, the first *old*, I believe, could simply be interpreted as *advanced in age*.

Comment: I explained my reasons. One doesn't use old old with or without a comma (which, by the way, cannot really be heard in speech) to mean anything other than a friend of very long standing. And I don't believe any native speaker would interpret old, old friend as advanced in age, unless otherwise specified by context. You cannot express both meanings simultaneously by repeating the word. That was the **whole point** of my answer.

Comment: I understand, but sometimes we get this kind of tunnel vision where we don't see the other interpretation unless other clues are provided. That's why I commented. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: At last, someone took pains to answer, and that someone is you; I like all the answers you take time to post to my silly, as it may seem. requests--upvote, upvote!!!

Comment: @Rompey I have to say that I probably take the time to answer them because I respond well to "cute". (I mean your name, by the way). :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have an **older** friend who is also an **old** friend.

*Older* may not be a widespread expression, but in my social circles it's a common and polite way to suggest someone is *middle-aged or over*, and usually much older than you are.

> There are a number of **older** people in my tennis club, and most of the time they beat the pants off the younger players.

*Older* can be used instead of *elderly*, which most often refers to someone of *advanced years* -- older than 75 or 80 -- and generally implies *frailty* or *infirmity*.

> I see many **elderly** women doing yoga, but they keep up with the rest of the class.

Comment: The idea is  how do you convey both at once?Also, if you are 20, 45 is older but, believe me, 45 is not old.

Comment: @Lambie  Yes, using *older* for someone who isn't particularly *old* might cause offense.  Such is the nature of language.  Anyway I don't think there is any way to mean both "at once".  The definitions don't overlap.  As you point out, even saying someone is an *old, old friend* normally implies emphasis, not two different meanings, and all your other examples include some explanation.

Comment: it's not that older might cause offense. It's that older does not necessarily mean "old". It can, of  course, be a euphemism for old but relative to an actual age can just mean several generations ahead of some age.

Comment: @Lambie  As I mention in my answer, "older" may not be a widespread euphemism.  It's more or less the same as ["of a certain age"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+a+certain+age) to imply "middle age or beyond", e.g. *"Do you know the name of that guy in our book club? He's an **older** man who always wears the same blue sweater."*